# PyPy: get raw access to string

Tags: python, cpython, pypy

In CPython, this works:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.pythonapi.PyString_AsString.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p,)
ctypes.pythonapi.PyString_AsString.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)

s = "abc"
cs = ctypes.pythonapi.PyString_AsString(id(s))
cs[0] = "x"

print s # will print 'xbc'
```

In PyPy, it does not because I cannot access the C-API this way.

Is there any way to do the same in PyPy?

Comment: Just checking: You don't use this thing in real code, right?

Comment: Just hacking/trying around. Whereby this should really be save/stable in CPython. And with this, you can do funny hacks, such as [this](https://github.com/albertz/playground/blob/master/test_importearlyexit.py). :)

Comment: For innocent bystanders (not the O.P. :-)  ): if you need a mutable string with assignable chars, use the "bytearray" Python object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not supposed to do that. The main reason is that PyPy has a movable garbage collector, so the pointer to it's contents might suddenly start pointing to garbage. The other reason is that we have few options that have a structure of say StringAdd(a, b), where there is really no underlying char* to refer to. Those optimizations are not on by default, but they'll probably be enabled soon.

Comment: Yea, that is what I thought. It's a pity, though. Well, not so much that immutable strings really are immutable but more that in some cases, it would have been nice (or it would have allowed nice hacks/possibilities) if mutable strings would have been used (like code objects, see [this](https://github.com/albertz/playground/blob/master/test_importearlyexit.py) hack).

Comment: use array from array module. Note that even if you manage to modify strings like this in PyPY, it's not safe, because JIT would do optimizations that will give you garbage.